# Pass a TextBox between two open forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two windows forms. F1 has a GridView of a table filled with data. Ideally the user clicks the "Export to Excel" button, a popup window form F2 would show up and ask user to type the file name to save in its TextBox and then go back to F1.

I tried several approaches online, including overloading constructor. It does help me pass the values between the two forms but it opens a new F1 with the user input after the user confirms a new filename. Basically I ended up with two F1 (one old one with my data in gridview, a new obe with user's input )

Can anyone advise?

I have tried this... http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/358513/pass-the-text-box-value-from-one-form-to-another-form-textbox

```
//form1:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 == null)
            f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ValueFromForm1(textBox1.Text);
        f2.Show();
    }
}

//form2:
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ValueFromForm1(string value)
    {
        textBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to show what you have tried.

Comment: When younsay "go back to 1" what would younlike to have happen? From your question, it is not clear what you intend to achieve. It seems to me you might also want to consider a more systematic approach such as MVC or similar patterns...

Comment: Usually, the best way to do it is to have a core program that is used by everything that can then be used to pass values between different forms.

Comment: What isn't working?  This code looks like it should create and show an instance of `Form2` and successfully supply to that instance a value from `Form1`.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Kris after user type a new file name and clicks a confirm button, F2 closes. The string user typed in would carry to the opened F1.

Comment: I am talking about having a core engine that runs all the forms and contains functions for them to run. You should not have a lot of code in you winforms, just function calls.

Comment: @David the problem is that it opens a new F1 instead of going back to my old F1

Comment: @CherylGuo: There is no code in the question which creates or shows an instance of `Form1`.  How is a second one being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an appropriate common dialog to select a file name. These common dialogs exists because common actions like open/save a file or choose a color or font should be the same across any application. Not using them force your users to learn a new user interface.
So it is recommended to use the common dialog (if there is no compelling reason to do differently)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls";
    if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       textBox1.Text = dlg.FileName;
}
```

See [SaveFileDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, if you really want to have your own form for select a file name then you need to change your code in this way

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using(Form2 f2 = new Form2())
    {
        // Pass the current text 
        f2.FileSelected = textBox1.Text;
        if(DialogResult.OK == f2.ShowDialog())
        {
            // read back the changes....
            textBox1.Text = f2.FileSelected;
        }
    }
}


//form2:
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // The property used to exchange the text between the two forms
    public string FileSelected {get;set;}

    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Let the user edit an initial value
        textBoxOnForm2.Text = this.FileSelected;
    }

    private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the edited text to the property
        this.FileSelected = textBoxOnForm2.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I ended up using the common dialog you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you're not necessarily trying to pass a value from `Form1` to `Form2`, but from `Form2` *back* to `Form1`.  To do this, don't open an instance of `Form1` from within `Form2`, but rather create `Form2` to have a *reference* back to the *original* `Form1` and you can set a value on that reference.  Something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    // other stuff

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 == null)
            f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Show();
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 Form1Reference { get; set; }

    // other stuff

    public Form2(Form1 form1Reference)
    {
        Form1Reference = form1Reference;
    }
}
```

Now you can access and set values on the open instance of `Form1` from within `Form2`.  For example, if `Form1` has a property:

```
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Then within the instance of `Form2` you can get/set that property:

```
Form1Reference.SomeValue = textBox1.Text;
```